# Open CMD as Administrator by using runas in the command which is set in Registry key-value

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, registry, runas

As I mentioned in the question, if Powershell can invoke the CMD as administrator by merely providing verb RunAs when opening new instance of CMD, then why CMD cannot open its own new instance with `runas` verb ?

I know that this command when passed in registry and set as value under `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas1\command]` key works:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs 'cmd.exe' -Args '/k pushd "%1"'"
```

But then why this doesn't work when given under that same key ??

```
cmd.exe /s /c "runas /user:administrator cmd /s /k pushd ""%V"""
```

How can I just use `cmd` and `runas` only to open CMD as Administrator ?

Comment: I guess you need to run runas.exe to start cmd as administrator. In a command box type `runas /?` to see the options

Comment: I have seen the details of `runas` and also I know that this works fine `runas /user:administrator cmd` , but my **specific** question is why `runas` doesn't allow cmd with switches to open up especially when set inside Registry key ? If Powershell with runAs allows it then why can't `cmd` open it's own instance with `runas` ? Have you tried setting the above in registry key, why it doesn't work in registry key ??

Answer (score 5):

RunAs.exe has nothing to do with the runas verb!

RunAs.exe has existed since Windows 2000 and allows you to run applications as different users. It is going to end up calling some version of `CreateProcess`.

The runas verb however needs to be invoked by `ShellExecute`.

In Windows 2000 and XP the runas verb displayed [a GUI](https://superuser.com/q/452427/658) that operated in a similar fashion to RunAs.exe.

In Vista the runas verb was changed to UAC elevate instead. RunAs.exe does not elevate.